# Codeigniter: Parsing array data in view in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

i want to multidimensional array to my view and then use this array to build form

This is what i've in my controller

```
function signin(){
    $attributes = array(
        'name'  =>  
        array(
            'name'        =>    'name',
            'type'        =>    'text',
            'placeholder'     =>     '' ,
            'value'       =>    'value'
            ),
        'password'                =>    
            array(
            'name'        =>    'name',
            'type'        =>    'password',
            'placeholder' =>      '',

            ),
        'gender' => 
            array(
            'name'        =>    'name',
            'type'        =>    'select',
                        'value'=>       
                            array(
                 'male','female'
            ),
        ),

        'usertpye'=>array(
            'type'                =>      'radio',
            'seller'          =>    'seller',
            'buyer'       =>    'buyer'
        ),
        'upload'=>array(
            'type'            =>      'file',
            'name'        =>    'file'
        ),

        'submit'=>array(
            'type'        =>    'submit',
            'name'        =>    'submit',
            'value'       =>    'submit'

        )

    );
        $this->load->view('login',$attributes);

}
```

in my view **login** i can access these items like **$name** or **$password** but  i want to fetch in a loop.really have no idea how can i do it please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load function receives an array, which keys then parses as variables in the view. Thus, you get variables like $name, $password etc.
Just add another layer before calling the load function like:

```
$data['attributes'] = $attributes;
```

And then, when loading the view do

```
$this->load->view('login',$data);
```

Here is the array a bit adjusted:

```
$attributes = array(
    'name'  =>  
    array(
        'name'        =>    'name',
        'type'        =>    'text',
        'placeholder' =>     '' ,
        'value'       =>    'value'
        ),
    'password'                =>    
        array(
        'name'        =>    'name',
        'type'        =>    'password',
        'placeholder' =>    '',

        ),
    'gender' => 
        array(
        'name'    =>    'name',
        'type'    =>    'select',
        'options' =>     array(
             'male'   => 'Male',
             'female' => 'Female'
        ),
    ),

    'usertpye'=>array(
        'type'   =>     'radio',
        'values' => array(
            'seller' =>    'seller',
            'buyer'  =>    'buyer'
        )
    ),
    'upload'=>array(
        'type' =>      'file',
        'name' =>    'file'
    ),

    'submit'=>array(
        'type'        =>    'submit',
        'name'        =>    'submit',
        'value'       =>    'submit'

    )
);
```

Here is how it would look like with the form helper of CI (this would go in the view, remember to first load the helper in the controller):

```
echo form_open('email/send');
foreach($attributes as $key=>$attribute) {
    echo form_label($key).'<br/>';
    if($attribute['type'] == 'select') {
        echo form_dropdown($attribute['name'],$attribute['options']).'<br/>';
    } elseif($attribute['type'] == 'radio') {
        foreach ($attribute['values'] as $value) {
            echo form_label($value);
            echo form_radio(array('name' => $key, 'value' => $value)).'<br/>';
        }
    } else {
        echo form_input($attribute).'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Note I did some adjustments to your initial attributes array to make it work, but you'd still need to improve its structure, add unique names for all items etc.

Comment: that seems good but problem is passing this data to form i want to generate form out of it and unable to find the way to do it

Comment: Are you using plain html or CI's form helper?

Comment: i am using form helper

Comment: for this i think i will have to use core php to parse md array  fine ?